# How do I show the last visit on my website with a cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

The basic idea is that every time somebody visits the website the cookie saves the time and date. If the user then visits the website multiple times the cookie only shows the date and time when the user last visited.
At the moment I have the following code which does work put obviously always updates the date and time:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours()+':'+today.getMinutes()+':'+today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' at '+time;
document.cookie ='last_visit='+ dateTime
```

Edit:For other people who might need help, the following code seems to work:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours()+':'+today.getMinutes()+':'+today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' at '+time;
function getCookieValue(a) {
    const b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
}
console.log ("getCookieValue " + getCookieValue("last_visit"));
document.cookie ='last_visit='+ dateTime
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider "visit" to mean?

Comment: Just *read* the cookie before overwriting it, and if it exists, display the stored time.

Comment: the last time someone or I visited the site. For example I visited the site on
1.1.2020
1.7.2021
3.1.2022 (would be today/current visit)
I want the cookie to show me:
last_visited       1.7.2021

Comment: @ChrisG how can I do this? I'm completely new to js, sorry

Comment: @ChrisG yeah seems like I got it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot share visited data between users on the cookies without receiving data from the server.

The solution is to save the last visit DateTime into the Database and send it back to the client

Comment: I do not think he wants to share this information between users.